# Is there anyway i can go into a module in Intellij like in eclipse?

Tags: intellij-idea

As i have many modules in the maven  project , would appreciate if i can go into a specific module in IntelliJ, such that i could see only that module in the project explorer. I have done this in eclipse however couldnt figure anything out IntelliJ idea. Please help.

Comment: A quick workaround: create a scope for your module (Settings > Appearance > Scopes), and it will appear in your project view drop down box. You need to create a scope for each module you want to filter, though, so it's not an ideal solution.

Comment: Thanks, that is the best possible solution i have across. Works for me for now .